# Trouble creating SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite

I am attempting to create an SQLite database, but it is giving me an error I will post code below.

```
public class DBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "waiters.db";
    public static final String TABLE_WAITERINFO = "waiterinfo";
    public static final String COLUMN_KEY = "key";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";

    public DBHandler(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_WAITERINFO + "(" +
                COLUMN_KEY + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT, " +
                ");";
        db.execSQL(query);
    }
```

this is the code which is giving the error.

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ")": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE waiterinfo(key INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT, );
                                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:887)
                                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:498)
                                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
                                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1674)
                                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1605)
                                                                                            at com.example.drooler1.assignment_17680817.DBHandler.onCreate(DBHandler.java:25)
                                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:251)
                                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
                                                                                            at com.example.drooler1.assignment_17680817.DBHandler.addWaiter(DBHandler.java:38)
                                                                                            at com.example.drooler1.assignment_17680817.AdminActivity.addWaiter(AdminActivity.java:30)
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

This is the error

Comment: Remove the comma in `" TEXT, "`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is fairly clear

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ")": syntax error
```

---

To fix it, remove the comma at

```
COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT, "
```

To this

```
COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT"
```